# Get sizeof C++ class in static member without using the class's name

Tags: c++

```
struct MyClass {
  unsigned a;
  // ...

  static constexpr unsigned size_this = sizeof(*this); // Doesn't work
  static constexpr unsigned size_type = sizeof(MyClass); // Works in gcc ...
  // but I need the name "MyClass" in source.
};
```

I realize that you cannot access `this` inside of a `static` members.

I'm basically looking for a way to reference the current class's type from a static member function **without** using the class's name directly.
Ultimately this is to be used with a preprocessor step that wouldn't otherwise need to know the name of the current class.

I feel like there should be some simple way to do this but I haven't found it after a bunch of searching while hoping to find some magical keyword like `decltype` that I'd forgotten.

---

Compiler info:

```
 ;  GNU C++14 (AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.6.2_1778) version 5.4.0 (avr)
 ;  compiled by GNU C version 4.7.4, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.0.0, MPC version 0.9
 ;  GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
 ;  options passed:  -I src -I lufa -I AVR++ -I libCameron/src
 ;  -imultilib avr5
 ;  -iprefix c:\program files (x86)\microchip\avr8-gnu-toolchain-win32_x86\bin\../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/
 ;  -MMD .bld/main.cpp.d -MF .bld/.dep/main.cpp.S.d -MP -MQ .bld/main.cpp.S
 ;  -D__AVR_ATmega32U4__ -D__AVR_DEVICE_NAME__=atmega32u4
 ;  -D F_CPU=16000000ULL -D ARCH=ARCH_AVR8 -D F_USB=16000000ULL
 ;  -D USE_LUFA_CONFIG_HEADER -U AVR src/main.cpp -mn-flash=1 -mmcu=avr5
 ;  -auxbase-strip .bld/main.cpp.S -O3 -Wall -Wfatal-errors -std=gnu++14
 ;  -fshort-enums -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fno-strict-aliasing
 ;  -fpack-struct -ffunction-sections -fverbose-asm -mn-flash=1
 ;  -mno-skip-bug -fno-rtti -fno-enforce-eh-specs -fno-exceptions
 ;  options enabled:  -Wmisspelled-isr -faggressive-loop-optimizations
 ;  -falign-functions -falign-jumps -falign-labels -falign-loops
 ;  -fauto-inc-dec -fbranch-count-reg -fchkp-check-incomplete-type
 ;  -fchkp-check-read -fchkp-check-write -fchkp-instrument-calls
 ;  -fchkp-narrow-bounds -fchkp-optimize -fchkp-store-bounds
 ;  -fchkp-use-static-bounds -fchkp-use-static-const-bounds
 ;  -fchkp-use-wrappers -fcombine-stack-adjustments -fcommon -fcompare-elim
 ;  -fcprop-registers -fcrossjumping -fcse-follow-jumps -fdefer-pop
 ;  -fdevirtualize -fdevirtualize-speculatively -fdwarf2-cfi-asm
 ;  -fearly-inlining -feliminate-unused-debug-types
 ;  -fexpensive-optimizations -fforward-propagate -ffunction-cse
 ;  -ffunction-sections -fgcse -fgcse-after-reload -fgcse-lm -fgnu-runtime
 ;  -fgnu-unique -fguess-branch-probability -fhoist-adjacent-loads -fident
 ;  -fif-conversion -fif-conversion2 -findirect-inlining -finline
 ;  -finline-atomics -finline-functions -finline-functions-called-once
 ;  -finline-small-functions -fipa-cp -fipa-cp-alignment -fipa-cp-clone
 ;  -fipa-icf -fipa-icf-functions -fipa-icf-variables -fipa-profile
 ;  -fipa-pure-const -fipa-ra -fipa-reference -fipa-sra
 ;  -fira-hoist-pressure -fira-share-save-slots -fira-share-spill-slots
 ;  -fisolate-erroneous-paths-dereference -fivopts -fkeep-static-consts
 ;  -fleading-underscore -flifetime-dse -flra-remat -flto-odr-type-merging
 ;  -fmath-errno -fmerge-constants -fmerge-debug-strings
 ;  -fmove-loop-invariants -fomit-frame-pointer -foptimize-sibling-calls
 ;  -foptimize-strlen -fpack-struct -fpartial-inlining -fpeephole
 ;  -fpeephole2 -fpredictive-commoning -fprefetch-loop-arrays
 ;  -freg-struct-return -freorder-blocks -freorder-functions
 ;  -frerun-cse-after-loop -fsched-critical-path-heuristic
 ;  -fsched-dep-count-heuristic -fsched-group-heuristic -fsched-interblock
 ;  -fsched-last-insn-heuristic -fsched-rank-heuristic -fsched-spec
 ;  -fsched-spec-insn-heuristic -fsched-stalled-insns-dep -fschedule-fusion
 ;  -fsemantic-interposition -fshow-column -fshrink-wrap -fsigned-zeros
 ;  -fsplit-ivs-in-unroller -fsplit-wide-types -fssa-phiopt -fstdarg-opt
 ;  -fstrict-overflow -fstrict-volatile-bitfields -fsync-libcalls
 ;  -fthread-jumps -ftoplevel-reorder -ftrapping-math -ftree-bit-ccp
 ;  -ftree-builtin-call-dce -ftree-ccp -ftree-ch -ftree-coalesce-vars
 ;  -ftree-copy-prop -ftree-copyrename -ftree-dce -ftree-dominator-opts
 ;  -ftree-dse -ftree-forwprop -ftree-fre -ftree-loop-distribute-patterns
 ;  -ftree-loop-if-convert -ftree-loop-im -ftree-loop-ivcanon
 ;  -ftree-loop-optimize -ftree-loop-vectorize -ftree-parallelize-loops=
 ;  -ftree-partial-pre -ftree-phiprop -ftree-pre -ftree-pta -ftree-reassoc
 ;  -ftree-scev-cprop -ftree-sink -ftree-slp-vectorize -ftree-slsr
 ;  -ftree-sra -ftree-switch-conversion -ftree-tail-merge -ftree-ter
 ;  -ftree-vrp -funit-at-a-time -funswitch-loops -fverbose-asm
 ;  -fzero-initialized-in-bss
```

Comment: "*I feel like there should be some simple way to do this*" - nope, there isn't one.  Unless you wrap the declaration of the `struct` inside a proprocessor macro that takes the struct name as a parameter (or otherwise generates a name).

Comment: You can create an alias for the class itself with a common name, e.g. `using Self = MyClass;`. Then you can use `Self` instead of `decltype(*this)`.

Comment: @user17732522 That still requires the struct to use its own name, though.

Comment: Despite `sizeof(MyClass)` working on whatever compiler you're using, it is not legal C++, as the class is incomplete when you're trying to use `sizeof`

Comment: @RemyLebeau It would require adding the alias to every affected class, but that might be feasible depending on the use case. If it is not, as you are saying, there is no other way.

Comment: What version of gcc (or which flags) are you using? Every version I've tested rejects the code (unless you're doing something else to trick it into compiling)

Comment: If what you want to do worked worked then you would need to use `MyClass::size_this` to access the class size.  This seems more complicated than `sizeof(MyClass)`.  This is feeling to me like an XY-problem.

Comment: @RichardCritten You can use instances to access static members: `myInstance.size`. @Salvage I've added compiler info for reference. I'd be curious to see why this would actually be incomplete according to the standard, but that's maybe a different question.

Comment: @CameronTacklind Without specific exception ("complete-class context") the class is imcomplete inside its whole body and `sizeof` requires the type to be complete. Initializer's of static data members are not in complete-class context, but default member initializers of non-static members or function bodies would be complete-class contexts.

Comment: @CameronTacklind Also note that this behaves differently in templates. If this was a class template or otherwise a templated entity, and nothing inside the class required the value of `size_this` when the class is instantiated, then there wouldn't be problem either.

Comment: @user17732522 Good point about non-`static` class members possibly referencing `constexpr static` members. In my case, this can't happen and probably what makes it work.

Comment: Perhaps you can sketch, how you generate the static member, why you cannot insert the class name and how you use size. Then the answers had more possibilities to find a solution, as the direct way seems not to work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you are asking is not possible. `static` member of a class cannot refer to any specific instance of the class, and `*this` refer to a specific instance: itself. If you really wish to get its size, you have to remove `static` identifier, and `constexpr` identifier, as `*this` is not treated as `constexpr`. Furthermore, as other comment said, what you are trying to achieve is what `sizeof(<instancename>)` operator can do, in more complex way.

Comment: I understand why `*this` doesn't make sense inside of a static member and I need `constexpr` for other compile time optimizations. But `sizeof(*this)` (or `decltype(*this)` for that matter) have unambiguous meaning in the context of a static class member as far as I can see. So they *could* be made to work if the standards body decided to (not suggesting that I think they *should*, just existence proof). There could also be some other way, maybe compiler specific, to do this, hence the question.